# Как при submit'е нескольких форм получить одно и то же внешнее поле?

Tags: javascript, html

Причем это внешнее поле может изменяться(Вообще же нам важно только то, что значение на момент `submit'а` будет актуальным). Тег `form` [не подходит](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961976/11488556), так как он указывает не на список `id`, а на один `id`.
Пример:

```
<form id="mainForm1" action="/form">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="mainForm2" action="/form">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<input id="field" name="field"/>
```

Нужно передать поле с `id="field"` в обе формы(чтобы при `submit'е` каждой это поле отправлялось на сервер)

Comment: Можете отловить событие сабмита на формах, взять значение нужного элемента, отправить что нужно на бакенд.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko была такая мысль - просто по нажатии на кнопку отправить через ajax. Но это серьезное нагромождение кода. Ищу более легкий путь.

Comment: Более легкого пути нету. Разве только переделать на одну форму. Зачем вам две формы?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А у меня их не 2, а динамически изменяющееся кол-во. Проблему то я решил. Так как я их запрашиваю страницей, на которой нужное поле, я могу просто передать нужное поле на сервер, а он, в свою очередь, может сгенерировать по такому же полю внутри каждой из форм. Но выглядит как костыль, конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На JQuery решается просто (буквально в 2 строки для любого кол-ва динамически сгенерированных форм):

```
<form id="mainForm1" action="/form">
  <input type="hidden" name="field"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form id="mainForm2" action="/form">
  <input type="hidden" name="field"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<input id="field" name="field"/>

$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $('input[name="field"]', this).val($('#field').val());
});
```